# Prove that this function is well-defined, injective and surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ and $g$ be injective functions such that $f$ is a mapping from $A$ to $B$ and $g$ is a mapping from $B$ to $A$. Define an equivalence relation R on $A$ by $s_1= g \circ f (s_2)$ or $s_2= g \circ f (s_1)$. Define a similar equivalence relation on $B$. For $s \in A$, we write $[s]$ for the class in $A/R$. Similar for the class in $B/\bar R$.

Define a map $H : A/R \to B/\bar R$ by $H([s]) = [f(s)]$.

How can I prove that $H$ is well-defined, injective and surjective?

Comment: you haven't defined a map so how do we know?

Comment: ooops i forgot. sorry. i added it.

Comment: Have you considered that two equivalence classes that share an element are the same set?

Comment: I didn't get what you exactly mean. But i've been tackling with this problem for awhile (~10hours) and because that i started to get confused on definitions etc. This my progress so far, for well defined part,  say $s_1=g \circ f ) ^n (s_2)$ (w.l.o.g) then by adding $f$ to this equation, and using associvity, i get $f(s_1)=(f \circ g) ^n f(s_2)$ and by adding $g$ i get $g \circ f (s_1) = (g \circ f) ^(n+1) (s_2) $ so $[s_1] = [s_2]$. I think this proves if we put the values in the function but not sure if this is a good proof or not

Comment: If $c\in [a]$ and $c\in [b]$ then you have $[a]=[b]$. Keep in mind also well-definedness and injectivity are the same problem in opposite directions.

Comment: I think I've done a similar thing as I wrote on the upper post but not sure if it's correct or not

Answer (score 0):

First remark that the "similar equivalence relation on $B$" is, explicitly, $t_{1}\sim t_{2}$ if $t_{1}=fg(t_{2})$ or $t_{2}=fg(t_{1})$.

Recall the following definitions of a function $f:X\to Y$ being well-defined, injective, and surjective:

1. $f$ is well-defined if it assigns a unique output to every input, regardless of the representation of equivalent inputs.
2. $f$ is injective if for all $x,x'\in X$, $f(x)=f(x')$ implies that $x=x'$.
3. $f$ is surjective if, for all $y\in Y$, there exists an $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.

We proceed with $H:A/R\to B/\overline{R}$.

**Well-defined:**

Suppose $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ are two representatives of the equivalence class $[s]$. We must show that $f(s_{1})\sim f(s_{2})$ in $B$, so that $[f(s_{1})]=[f(s_{2})]$. Since $s_{1}\sim s_{2}$ in $A$, $s_{1}=gf(s_{2})$ or $s_{2}=gf(s_{1})$. Applying $f$ to both sides of both equations, we get $f(s_{1})=fg(f(s_{2}))$ or $f(s_{2})=fg(f(s_{1}))$, and therefore $f(s_{1})\sim f(s_{2})$, as desired.

**Injective:**

Suppose $H([s])=H([s'])$; we must show $[s]=[s']$. If $H([s])=H([s'])$, then $[f(s)]=[f(s')]$, so $f(s)\sim f(s')$. Thus $f(s)=fg(f(s'))$ or $f(s')=fg(f(s))$. As $f$ is injective, it is left-invertible, and therefore $s=gf(s')$ or $s'=gf(s)$. Hence $s\sim s'$, and $[s]=[s']$, as desired.

**Surjective:**

Let $y\in B/\overline{R}$; we must show that there exists $[s]\in A/R$ such that $H([s])=y$. If $y$ is in $B/\overline{R}$, then it has some representative, call it $b$, in $B$. Let $s=g(b)$. Then $H([s])=[f(g(b))]$. We are done if $fg(b)$ is also a representative of $y$; i.e., we must show $b\sim fg(b)$. This means we must show either $b=fg(fg(b))$ or $fg(b)=fg(b)$, but clearly this second equation is so. Hence $H([s])=y$, as we wished to show.